# Does the region, that my app is on, matter to the Amazon SES Free Tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

My app, that use SMTP to send emails, is on the Amazon EC2 **Canada (Central)** and Amazon SES is setup on **N. Virginia**.

According to the [Amazon SES Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/#AWS_Free_Usage_Tier):

> When you call Amazon SES from an application hosted in Amazon EC2, you can send 62,000 messages per month at no charge. This Free Usage Tier benefit does not expire.

Do I get this pricing sending emails from the another region? Or the region doesn't matter at all here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon SES free tier pricing doesn't depend on Region.